# TextBox selectors - which one is better

Tags: jquery

Which of the following selectors is better and why?

```
var txt = $('input[type="text"]')
```

or

```
var txt = $('input:text');
```

Comment: you forgot about `$(":text")` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/),

> :text selects input elements that have no specified type attribute (in which case type="text" is implied)

And,

> Because :text is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :text cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="text"] instead.

These should answer your question.